# What can be said about the distance between elements in a discrete subspace/subgroup?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I'm interested in discrete subspaces and (additive) subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I was interested in what can be said about the distance between elements in a discrete subspace/subgroup, in the sense of some lower bound for the distance.

The two canonical examples I have in mind are $\{1/m : m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^m$ (which is the only example for a subgroup up to isomorphism), for the first no such bound exists, and for the latter it is simply $1$.

Is it typical for subspaces vs subgroups?

I guess that what is needed is a classification of the isomorphisms of $R^n$ with itself, or maybe start with $n=1$ for simplicity as I did first, to understand the subgroup case (maybe find very contracting maps). It did not get me far though.

Comment: 'which is the only example for a subgroup up to isomorphism' 

Maybe I am missing something but $\mathbb{Q}^n$ seems to fit your criteria and is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as it has elements of order $n$ for each $n \geq 1$. Also, does subspace mean a topological subspace with no additional structure? If so, for any $s > 0$ you can pick two points $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $d(p,q) = s$.

Comment: @GuidoA. Good point about subgroups . Perhaps I was thinking only about lattices. So I am in fact interested in three cases, topological subspaces, topological subgroups, and lattices. I guess that your example solves the first two cases. I will edit the original question as soon as I can.